# Vertx PostgreSQL Transactions

Tags: java, postgresql, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to make a simple SQL Transaction, but unfortunately I can't get it to work right.

What I'm doing right now:

```
protected Single<SQLConnection> tx() {
  return PostgreSQLClient.createShared(getVertx(), SqlUtil.getConnectionData())
    .rxGetConnection().map((SQLConnection conn) -> {
 
    conn.rxSetAutoCommit(false);

    return conn;
  });
}
```

This should be enough from what I understand from reading the docs?

when I inspect `conn` I see:

> inTransaction = false
>
> isAutoCommit = true

Why is that and what am I doing wrong here?

--

I use the common sql driver (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sql-common) with vertx 3.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the internal state of the connection. The current implementation, controls transactionality using 2 flags:

- inTransaction
- isAutoCommit

The last one is flipped once you call the method:

```
conn.rxSetAutoCommit(false);
```

But this is handled internally as a NOOP. Only when a call is performed after the transaction will be started and the first flag will change.

Keep in mind that this is internal state of the client and can/will change in the future when proper transaction isolation levels are implemented in the async driver for which there is already a pending [pull request](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/pull/74).

If you want to see it working, basically issue a SQL statement in your code, e.g.:

```
conn.rxSetAutoCommit(false).rxExecute("SELECT ...")
```

and if you inspect again you will see that both flags are now true as well there is a running transaction on your server.

Comment: How i see, asker's problem in rx api. `rxSetAutoCommit` is `rx.Single` so there should be subscribing to it. But it returns `Single<Void>,` not `Single<Connection>`, so this fact make rx transformation with `map` harder.  But I may be wrong, just superficial galance ;)

Comment: @zella: I think I run into this issue. I already tried executing an insert, but on `conn.rxCommit()` I got the error `Not in transaction currently`. Does this mean transactions with flatMap aren't possible right now?

Comment: It's possible. Just need more transoformation with 'zip' and flatMap for example. Temporary you can call syncronous: rxSetAutocommit.toBlocking

Comment: thanks, but I guess I'll wait for the pull request for now